# Ember.js QT w/ Javascript Bridge

Tags: c++, node.js, qt, ember.js, ember-data

We have a full desktop application based in QT C++ (mac & windows). We utilize webkit to serve up the UI based in HTML and Javascript. We also interact with the C++ via a javascript bridge. I'm doing quite the overhall and incorporating Ember.js as the MVC for a much more modular UI.

My question pertains to the best method for persistance. Should I stick with the Javascript objects we currently utilize, or transition to Ember Data for persistence, and read/write via a function in Ember Data(translation layer)?

Also we utilize webkit, but should I see about instead utilising Node.js rather than strait html/js?

I'd like to not do drastic changes, but I want to do this right. Any advice?

Comment: Are you concerned from a Qt standpoint? It's not clear to me how Qt will be effected, here. Can you provide something more concrete? I've written hybrid apps and thin clients using Node.js, webkit,and Qt. On the Qt side of things, you just expose your Qt objects to javascript on the loaded page, call C++ functions with Q_INVOKABLE, and utilize signals and slots to bride the language gap if needed. How do you envision Ember.js changing this setup at all? You'll still have to go through the same steps on the Qt side of things, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ember side, there's no reason to use Ember Data, because Ember works fine without it.  But Ember's infrastructure relies heavily on the API provided by [`Ember.Observable`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html), which is available to all subclasses of [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html). Similarly, JavaScript arrays will support more Ember features if you use [`Ember.Array`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) and [`Ember.MutableArray`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html), although this will happen automatically unless you [disable `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES`](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/).

So one very reasonable approach would be to port your existing model classes to `Ember.Object`. That would require, among other things, using `get` and `set` to access properties. If you do this, then your objects will be first class Ember citizens, and you'll have access to all the neat features of Ember, including automatic view updates and data bindings.

Here's what `Ember.Object` looks like, and how it integrates with the rest of Ember:

```
MyApp.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  init: function () {
    // You can put more initialization code here.
  },

  // Compute fullName based on firstName and lastName.
  // This will automatically propagate updates when
  // firstName or lastName changes.
  fullName: function () {
    return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
  }.property("firstName", "lastName")
});

var person = MyApp.Person.create({ firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe" })
```

Then, in an Ember view, you could write something like:

```
<p>{{person.fullName}}</p>
```

…and the view would automatically updated whenever `firstName` or `lastName` changed. Similarly, you could edit `firstName` using the following code:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.firstName"}}
```

In this example, changes to the text field will be automatically propagated back to the underlying object. (Though you can get clever and build a text field that only propagates changes when the user is done editing.)

If you need to pass property updates from Ember to QT, see the [guide to building getters and setters with computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) or use [observers](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/). A lot depends on exactly how you're exposing your C++ APIs via your JavaScript bridge. But as long as you can tie into `Ember.Observable` somehow, you'll have full access to all of Ember's features.